# Select sum shown null value in left join SQL statement

Tags: sql-server-2000

I have three tables and expecting the result as below but i do not know how to correct my sql statement.

```
select history.company,history.ghacct,rpt_revenue.revenue,rpt_revenue.other, isnull(guest.stay,0) as stay, isnull(guest.nights,0) as nights
from history
left join(select company,count(*) as stay,sum(nights) as nights from guest group by company) guest on guest.company=history.company
left join (select ghacct,sum(revenue) as revenue, sum(other) as other
from rpt_revenue group by ghacct) rpt_revenue on rpt_revenue.ghacct=history.ghacct
where history.type='c' group by history.company, history.ghacct,rpt_revenue.revenue, rpt_revenue.other,guest.stay,guest.nights order by history.company asc;
```

history

```
ghacct company type
33 JOINT LTD 10010205687 c
3B GLOBAL   10010350619 c
3E FASHION  10010244145 c
3P INT'L        10010112089 c
```

guest

```
company     stay        nights
33 JOINT LTD    01/01/2009  1
33 JOINT LTD    01/06/2009  1
3B GLOBAL   10/02/2019  2
3E FASHION  09/25/2008  6
3P INT'L        08/26/2009  3
3P INT'L        04/26/2010  9
```

rpt_revenue

```
ghacct      revenue other
10010205687 20  10
10010205687 10  10
10010350619 30  2
10010244145 15  3
10010112089 16  8
10010112089 4   2
```

Result

```
company     ghacct      revenue other   stay    nights
33 JOINT LTD    10010205687 NULL    NULL    2   2
3B GLOBAL   10010350619 NULL    NULL    1   2
3E FASHION  10010244145 NULL    NULL    1   6
3P INT'L        10010112089 NULL    NULL    2   12
```

Expected result

```
company     ghacct      revenue other   stay    nights
33 JOINT LTD    10010205687 30  20  2   2
3B GLOBAL   10010350619 30  2   1   2
3E FASHION  10010244145 15  3   1   6
3P INT'L        10010112089 20  10  2   12
```

Comment: can you please explain what are you trying to achieve ? What is wrong with your existing query

Comment: Please format your query so that other may have an easier time understanding it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the main problem with your current query lies in the `GROUP BY` clause, which should really only be aggregating by company and account.  In addition, you might want to use `ISNULL` for the revenue and other amount, as you are already doing so for stay and nights.

```
SELECT
    h.company,
    h.ghacct,
    ISNULL(rr.revenue, 0) AS revenue,
    ISNULL(rr.other, 0)   AS other,
    ISNULL(g.stay, 0)     AS stay,
    ISNULL(g.nights, 0)   AS nights
FROM history h
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT company, COUNT(*) AS stay, SUM(nights) AS nights
    FROM guest
    GROUP BY company
) g
    ON g.company = h.company
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT ghacct, SUM(revenue) AS revenue, SUM(other) AS other
    FROM rpt_revenue
    GROUP BY ghacct
) rr
    ON rr.ghacct = h.ghacct
WHERE
    h.type = 'c'
GROUP BY
    h.company,
    h.ghacct
ORDER BY
    h.company;
```